# Facing issue in informatica admin console

Tags: informatica

I have installed informatica 10.1 in my windows 10 machine, and the installation completed successfully. During installation i was able to connect to Admin web-page.

But, once i restarted my pc, I was not able to login Adminpage.

I am new to informatica

Please help.

Comment: Plz provide a solution on my query???

Comment: Sorry but we'll need more info to go on e.g. when I try to log on I get x error or when I type in the admin console url I hit a 404 error... without some understanding its impossible to help

Comment: when i type informatica admin colsole link in url ,i m getting 'This site can’t be reached

lokesh refused to connect.
Search Google for lokesh 6008
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED' error msg ,how to fixed this issue

Comment: You need to bypass the proxy in the browser you use

Comment: How to bypass the proxy in browser???could u plz help me !!!